# Cannot execute 1st command in AWS Glue Notebook

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I create a AWS Glue Notebook, I run step 1 in the block:

```
%glue_version 3.0
%worker_type G.1X
%number_of_workers 5
%%configure 
{ 
    "region": "ap-xxxxxxx-2", 
    "iam_role": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/IAM_Glue_Role"
}

import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
  
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
```

The output is like this:

```
Current idle_timeout is 2880 minutes.
idle_timeout has been set to 2880 minutes.
Setting Glue version to: 3.0
Previous worker type: G.1X
Setting new worker type to: G.1X
Previous number of workers: 5
Setting new number of workers to: 5
```

But I also get an error like this:

```
The following exception was encountered while parsing the configurations provided: invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 6) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jupyter-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aws_glue_interactive_sessions_kernel/glue_pyspark/GlueKernel.py", line 436, in configure
    configs = ast.literal_eval(configs_json)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/ast.py", line 46, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 7
    import sys
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please help me to solve this out.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that using magic commands at the top of notebook cells prevents the kernel from interpreting your Spark code as such.

You should run your config code (below) as a separate cell in your notebook, then your spark code as another separate cell.

```
%glue_version 3.0
%worker_type G.1X
%number_of_workers 5
%%configure 
{ 
    "region": "ap-xxxxxxx-2", 
    "iam_role": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/IAM_Glue_Role"
}
```